# Parsing an RDF file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, rdf

Does anyone know how to parse RDF file in Python to get all the values within a specific tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using an RDF library? Otherwise, perhaps you should. For example, see the documentation of three RDF libraries for Python:

- [Redland RDF libraries](http://librdf.org/)
- [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib)
- [RDF/XML parser](http://infomesh.net/2003/rdfparser/)